# How to set credentials through cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have a cloudformation template that spins up an ec2 instance. Once I am in this ec2 instance, I tried to retrieve a file from an s3 bucket. However, in order to do this, I had to put in my credentials using aws configure (Access Key, Secret Access Key, region, etc...). Is there a way to automatically have these credentials set by the time I ssh into my instance? I was thinking of putting the credentials somewhere in the cloudformation template, but this seems a little weird. Where would the credentials be put?

Thank you

Comment: You need to do the aws configure only once. So that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a role to your instance. Here's an example

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Attach IAM Role to an EC2
Resources:
  Test:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType:
        Ref: InstanceType
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Ref: ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile
  ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
      - Ref: ListS3BucketsRole
  ListS3BucketsPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: ListS3BucketsPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - s3:List*
          Resource: "*"
      Roles:
      - Ref: ListS3BucketsRole
  ListS3BucketsRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
```

`ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile` assumes the role : `ListS3BucketsRole` .
`ListS3BucketsPolicy` is attached to `ListS3BucketsRole` which allows the role to list all s3 objects.

With this your EC2 instance can list files on S3